# How to set and test PWM "Duty Cycle" to a AC motor?

Tags: rpm, pwm

I'm new to PWM.
But now we have a project needs to control a AC motor via PWM, but we found the duty cycle we set to run AC motor is so unstable.
Sometimes I set "50% of duty cycle" and "20 ms" and I will get a steady state, but when I want to get higher rpm, so I raised my duty cycle to 70%, Then the AC motor will slow down slowly until it stops...
That's why I have no idea how to try these variables...

I will be very appreciate if someone can give me a hint, thanks a lot!

Comment: Need to figure out what your signal is actually doing to the motor driver.  What happens when you put it to perpetually high or low? ( 100% duty cycle and 0% duty cycle).  It could be that you are using the driver incorrectly (frequency based like a stepper), or your pwm is too slow (and you may need additional smoothing)